# Renaming key value of hashmap instead of reinserting

Tags: java, hashmap

As the title says is there a simple way to change the key of my hashmap?

Here I update all the values of my hashmap

```
stock.put(itemCode.getText(), new StockData.Item(itemName.getText(),(Double) priceS.getValue(), (Integer)quantityS.getValue(), file.getName()));
```

and now I would like to change the key, I used earlier removing and inserting data that worked but the order was changed which I don't want to happen.

Comment: A `HashMap` _has no order_. What do you mean by "_the order was changed_"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a `HashMap`, your keys should never change after insertion.

If the order matters to you, you should be using an implementation of a `SortedMap` (e.g. `TreeMap`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.
A `HashMap` has no order, objects are inserted based on the hash value of the key, if you change the key, you change its hash and thus the bucket it appears in inside the `HashMap`.  If you want to order the map you are better off using a `TreeMap`

We hit this problem moving from Java 7 to Java 8 several tests asserted the contents of a HashMap based on the `HashMaps` `toString` value, this has no determined order, but under Java 7 it seemed to work but the tests failed under Java 8.

Comment: Or a `LinkedHashMap` - depends what the OP want.

Comment: "_several tests asserted the contents of a `HashMap` based on the `HashMaps` `toString` value_". Ooops...

Comment: @BoristheSpider yeah! Tell me about it :S

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` doesn't guarantee the order of the items, their location inside the `HashMap` is determined by the `hashcode` which is calculated from the key. Therefor changing the key will change the location, as you actually removing the previous `key value` entry and inserting a new entry.

From `HashMap` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.